# Pegar imagem tirada pela camera e colocar no ImageView (AndroidStudio JAVA)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, picture

boa tarde a todos! Fiz um código que quando o usuário preciona o botão ele abre para o usuário poder selecionar uma imagem da galeria ou tirar uma foto direto da camera, a parte do usuário selecionar a foto na galeria e o código pegar essa foto e colocar na imageview está funcionando, porém quando vou para a camera eu tiro a foto e a imagemview está ficando branca... Alguém sabe onde estou errando?? Obrigado pela atenção desde já. (quando preciono o botão ele chama a função escolherFonteDaFoto()).

```
private void escolherFonteDaFoto() {
        Intent escolherFotoIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        Intent tirarFotoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(escolherFotoIntent, "Selecionar ou tirar foto");
        chooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, new Intent[]{tirarFotoIntent});

        startActivityForResult(chooser, REQUEST_IMAGE_PICK);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_PICK && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (data != null && data.getData() != null) {
                // Foto selecionada da galeria
                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                try {
                    Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), selectedImageUri);
                    ivUser.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        } else if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // Foto tirada usando a câmera
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            if (extras != null) {
                Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
                ivUser.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
            }
        }
    }
```